# Need to find whether an array is empty or not in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to find whether an array is empty or not. If it is empty I want to add data and if it is not it will not allow adding. I am currently stuck at the following stage,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
export default {
    name: 'CarrierCosts',
    data () {
        return {
            inputs: [],

            form: {
                free_shipping: '',
                add_handling_costs: '',
                tax: '',
                range: '',
                checkboxValue: '',
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addRange(){         
            this.inputs.push({
                rangField: '',
            })
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: check `this.inputs.length` and do whatever you want

Comment: I need to know that before to push to an array. But its not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could know that array is empty by checking its length:

```
methods: {
    addRange(){  
     if(this.inputs.length===0){       
        this.inputs.push({
            rangField: '',
        })
        }
    },
}
```